# Current drawn by microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, current, adc, embedded, interface

How to estimate current drawn by microcontroller(on the ADC port) when interfaced to a module/IC/sensor theoretically?

MCU manual: https://nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC2131_32_34_36_38.pdf

Comment: If you can give us a link to the datasheet for your microcontroller, we can probably show you where this is specified.

Comment: @ThePhoton https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC2131_32_34_36_38.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of the pin you are interested in are the "LOW-level input current" and "HIGH-level input current". In case of that MCU it is 3 µA.

For the ADC you also have to factor in the sample and hold capacitance which is the "analog input capacitance" (1 pf). Also look at figure 12 "Suggested ADC interface", it shows the ADC input in more detail.

Comment: will it be right to say that this the load current if we are measuring the power consumed by the sensor?

Comment: Sensor power consumption and sensor output current are (almost) totally independent. You can have a sensor that consumes 5W to run a heater and still outputs just 1 mA signal.

Comment: So now if I need to calculate the power consumed by a sensor(specifically analog type temp sensor) interfaced to my controller, I need to find P=VI, where V is the supply voltage and I is the sum of load current and quiescent current at that very temperature. So what should I take as the load current?

Comment: Which sensor? Thermocouple? Pt100? LM35? Provide a datasheet.

Comment: LM35 https://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/LM35.PDF

Comment: In this case this is LM35 quiescent current + its output current (that goes to the ADC).

Comment: Load current on the sensor is either 3 uA (according to this answer) or something less than 1 uA (according to my answer).  Given that quiescent current is over 100 uA, it won't really matter which one you choose.

Comment: How to find that output current? Is it the supply voltage of sensor divided by the R(voltage source interface resistance) mentioned in the datasheet of  the controller.

Comment: The sensor's output current is the ADC input current (until you reach the absolute maximum ratings of the sensor output).

Comment: @filo   How to find that output current? Is it the supply voltage of sensor divided by the R(voltage source interface resistance) mentioned in the datasheet of the controller. Is this how ADC's input current is calculated? Please confirm? or should I simply take it as the high level input current 3uA of the controller?

Comment: @ThePhoton How to calculate that 1uA?

Comment: You have a voltage source (the sensor) and you have a load/consumer (the ADC). Within all the parameters specified in the MCU datasheet (like temperature and supply voltage) the maximum current the ADC will consume is 1 (or 3) µA. It is simply provided by the datasheet. It can be smaller in practice. There is really nothing to find - it is read of the datasheet.

Comment: @Megh, I showed how in my answer. Given the specs filo pointed out, though, I am not sure the datasheet is 100% self-consistent, and to be conservative you should probalby use the 3 uA figure.

Comment: In any case, if what you're worried about is the sensor self-heating, remember that some (most) of the power consumption due to the load current happens in the load, not the sensor. Given that and how much smaller it is than the quiescent current, you can almost surely just ignore the load current.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have one more doubt, The high level input current of the controller is same for all the pins. So now if I have to calculate the power budget of an embedded system, all I need to do is multiply the supply voltages of different ICs with this value of current and sum them all??

Comment: @Megh, only two (IIRC) of the pins are ADC inputs. If you have a bunch of digital devices connected to the other pins, you should probably open a new question to ask about that situation.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specified directly in your [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC2131_32_34_36_38.pdf), but there are a couple of clues in there.

First, there's a spec for the maximum resistance of the sensor or signal conditioning circuit that drives the ADC:

[image]

where Note 8 refers us to Figure 11:

[image]

The limit on the source resistance tells us that the maximum input leakage current, when run through a 40 kΩ resistor, won't cause a voltage drop big enough to disturb the ADC reading (by more than the specified absolute error of counts). Taking the minimum VDDA value of 2.6 V, divided by the resolution of the ADC of 1024 levels, this implies

$$I_l < 4 \frac{2.5\ {\rm mV}}{40\ {\rm k\Omega}}$$

or about 252 nA.

From this we can infer an input resistance of 10 MΩ or greater.

But note in the input equivalent circuit, you must also consider the input capacitance if your signal is varying somewhat quickly over time.